# FromBody ViewModel is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm doing a post of web api with ajax. But ApiController doesn't get values. My ViewModel is null. In Startup.cs I already manage with Automapper to map viewmodel with entity, other part of application is working it is done on same way. Probably is something very stupid, but at the moment I can't find where is the mistake.

> Update:
>   I tried with postman to simulate posting web api, even there I can't post. So what I can understand from this is next: Problem it can be only in next two things controller or viewmodel. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
  [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("/api/v1/items")]
    public class SparePartApiController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository<SparePart> _repoSparePart;

        public SparePartApiController(IRepository<SparePart> repoSparePart)
        {
            _repoSparePart = repoSparePart;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]SparePartViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newItem = Mapper.Map<SparePart>(viewModel);
                newItem.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                var exist = _repoSparePart.SearchByName(w => string.Equals(w.InternalCode, viewModel.InternalCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                if (exist != null)
                {
                    TempData["items"] = "Spare Part already exist.";
                }
                else
                {
                    _repoSparePart.Insert(newItem);
                    if (await _repoSparePart.SaveChangesAsync())
                    {
                        TempData["items"] = "Spare Part successfully created";
                        return Created($"items/{newItem.InternalCode}", Mapper.Map<SparePart>(viewModel));
                    }
                }
            }
            return BadRequest("Failed to save.");
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Items";
}
<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New Item</button><br /><br />
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>*@
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="item-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Id">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Id" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="InternalCode">Internal Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internalCode" placeholder="Internal Code" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Description">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="NameOnFolder">Name On Item</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameOnFolder" placeholder="Name On Folder" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Enter">Enter</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="enter" placeholder="Enter" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Exit">Exit</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="exit" placeholder="Exit" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Thickness">Thickness</label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="thickness" placeholder="Thickness" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Band">Band</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="band" placeholder="Band" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Color">Color</label>
                        <input type="text" id="color" class="form-control" placeholder="Color" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Elastic">Elasitc</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="elastic" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="MachineType">Machine Type</label>
                        <select id="machineType" class="form-control">
                            <option class="form-control" value="0">-- Select --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="SpareType">Spare Type</label>
                        <select id="spareType" class="form-control">
                            <option class="form-control" value="0">-- Select --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="AddItem()">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rows">

</div>


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/spare-part.js"></script>
}

function AddItem() {

    var item = {

        internalCode: $("#internalCode").val(),
        description: $("#description").val(),
        nameOnFolder: $("#nameOnFolder").val(),
        enter: $("#enter").val(),
        exit: $("#exit").val(),
        thickness: $("#thickness").val(),
        band: $("#band").val(),
        color: $("#color").val(),
        elastic: $("#elastic").is(":checked"),
        machineType: $("#machineType").val(),
        spareType: $("#spareType").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/items',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            LoadItems();
            window.location.reload();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }, error: function (errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage.responseText);
            console.log(item);
        }
    });
}
```

SpartPartViewModel.cs

```
public class SparePartViewModel
{
    public Int64? Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string InternalCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4096)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string NameOnFolder { get; set; }

    public decimal? Enter { get; set; }

    public decimal? Exit { get; set; }

    public decimal? Thickness { get; set; }

    public string Band { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public bool Elastic { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual MachineType MachineType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual SpareType SpareType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you missing the `CreateDate` form-group?

Comment: CreateDate it will be added in controller. Other part of codes are on same way and its  working.

Comment: Your inputs have no `name` attributes. You should probably define the view model in the view with `@model` and use proper bindings on the input fields.

Comment: @juunas no, that is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue. I do similar ajax call to an api controller to check if a subdomain name is available. The only difference I see between your code and mine is this follow:

```
 var data = {
                Guid: '@Model.Guid',
                UrlName: $(this).val()
            };   
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/api/ValidateUrlName',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "RequestVerificationToken": token
                },
               ...

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("ValidateUrlName")]
    public JsonResult ValidateUrlName([FromBody]ValidateEventUrlName data)
    {
```

You shouldn't need "var token" and the RequestVerificationToken header, that is for when you use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on the controller

Comment: No, that is not the issue.